# Why is memory consumption increases, than drops and stays constant

Tags: node.js, memory, node-streams

I have the following simple program:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const time = Date.now();
const file = fs.createWriteStream('./test.txt');

let written = true;

file.on('drain', function () {
    written = true;
});

const interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (Date.now() - time > 10000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    if (written) {
        written = file.write(new Array(1000000).join('z'));
        console.log(Math.floor(process.memoryUsage().rss / (1024 * 1024)));
    }
}, 100);
```

And the following memory consumption is logged:

29
38
48
58
67
77
86
96
105
115
125
134
144
153
163
173
182
192
201
211
220
230
240
249
259
268
278
287
297
307
316
326
335
345
355
364
374
383
393
402
412
422
431
441
450
460
470
479
489
498
508
518
527
537
546
556
565
575
585
561

87
97
25
35
44
25
35
44
25
35
44
25
35
44
25
35
44
25
35
44
25
35
44
25
35
44
25
35
44

As you may see it was growing to `561 MB`, but that dropped to `87 MB` and then stayed under `100 MB`. What happens here?

Comment: `new Array(1000000).join('z')` creates a string consisting of 999999 `z` characters. Just FYI, in any recent version of Node, you can use `"z".repeat(999999)` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating largely-empty temporary objects (`new Array(1000000)` just creates an empty array with `length` set to 1000000; it doesn't create an array with 1000000 entries) and then large temporary strings (and some housekeeping objects) every 100ms or so. At some point, it stops doing that (when you've set `written` to `true`).

After each iteration, the array and housekeeping objects will be eligible for garbage collection immediately, and the string once it's done being written to the file. But that doesn't mean they're cleaned up immediately.

Once the system stops doing that, eventually garbage collection kicks in and releases all of those objects and strings.

If the timer kept going, eventually you'd see GC even while it was running, but there's no significant memory pressure in your example so there was no reason to prioritize it.

Comment: yeah, I used `global.gc();` and now it stays constant at `22` with `'z'.repeat(1000000)`. so is my understanding correct that `gc` didn't do anything until I reached `561` and then started to clean after `44` as this pattern is continuously repeated `35 44 25`?

Comment: @Maximus: Probably along those lines, yeah. The ongoing work of running the interval timer and showing the memory usage probably involves creating (and then reclaiming) temporary objects.